# ApplicationPool identity and COMPUTERNAME$

Tags: iis, iis-8

I am user the newest version of IIS.

I understand that i have two option to grant permission to ApplicationPools:
(Take into account that my site needs to access other computers such SQL server and FileServer and i am not working with only one server).

1. Create a domain user with the minimal privileges for the application pool and the anonymous access and give to that user access to my SQL server and the file server file system. - Could someone advice whats are the minimal privileges needed for IIS Application pool user?
2. Using "IIS AppPool\MyAppPool" - This way, i can not grant access to my SQL server and my file server because this is a virtual user account that not exists in the SQL server and the file server so i can use the COMPUTERNAME$ for that. But on that way, i grant the same access to all my Application Pools users regarding the File Server and the SQL Server because all of them will access that servers using COMPUTERNAME$.  How can i still use that option but grant different permissions for every application pool user on the file server and the SQL server?

Comment: So your SQL Server runs on a different machine, correct?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933134/add-iis-7-apppool-identities-as-sql-server-logons

Comment: Very confusing description but to simplify, you should consider using a web.config file and setup the credential in there to authenticate to the SQL Server DB and grant it, etc. the minimal permissions to the SQL Server objects as needed. I've administered systems that allow IIS web access to sites (anonymously), IIS web access to the file system objects, and IIS web access to SQL Server DB objects, but your description sounds confusing for what you are trying to accomplish and it sounds like you are trying to make it harder than it really needs to be.